# Getting App Inventor 2 variable values in an HTML/Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, app-inventor

I am setting up a simple map program for a user to see locations on an embedded Google map. I have the map working, but I was wondering if there is a way for the user to input coordinates in AI2 then have the map  center there. 
Here is the HTML file I am using to display the map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
     <style type="text/css">
     html { height: 100% }
     body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
     #map_canvas { height: 100% }
     </style>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=true&language=en"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    // Add a listener for the click event
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', showPosition);
  }

  function showPosition(event) {
    // display a marker on the map
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map,
      icon: "./marker.png"
    });

    // print the selected position to the page title
    var position = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(6) + ", " + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(6);
    window.document.title = position;
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

You can use `WebViewString` to communicate values back and forth between your App and the `WebViewer`. In your App, you get and set the `WebViewer.WebViewString` properties. In your `webviewer`, you open to a page that has Javascript that references the window.AppInventor object, using its `getWebViewString()` and `setWebViewString(text)` methods.

See also the following [snippet](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2webviewstring) for a complete example.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta name="author" content="puravidaapps.com">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    document.write("The value from the app is<br />" + window.AppInventor.getWebViewString());
    window.AppInventor.setWebViewString("hello from Javascript")
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually was looking at your page on how to implement the map.